# IE doesnt load all html, other browsers do

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with Internet explorer on my page, it doesnt seem to load all the html. Firefox, opera, safari and chrome loads it all. 
The page is a masterpage but it seems to load randomly between 102 and 119 rows of code, it can even cut mid sentence.

Comment: from the ie console, `SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined 
hoverIntent.js, line 1 character 2` Include jquery before all your script files. It's also broken in chrome.

Comment: jquery core file is after all the plugins please add this  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 after title tag

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple, it worked 2 days ago though. Did they change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i hadnt loaded the jquerylib before i tried to call it, it worked before but now it seems ie just crashes and fails to load.